# What can I cover this shower handle with to hide the shaft?

Tags: shower, bathtub, cover

The shower handle has the shaft exposed. I want to cover it but I don't want to put the circular plate that Moen (mainly) sells. I don't want it cover the tiles. Just the shaft. Is there something available for this or should I do something custom?

Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You just want the shaft covered so it matches the faucet?  Would imagine someone has a chrome tube like piece that would fit the shaft.

Comment: Yes, just the shaft. Chrome tube ? Interesting. Where could I find this ?

Comment: Would try plumbing shop first,  maybe automotive shop second(piece of chrome exhaust pipe).  Need to have the outside diameter of shaft and length.  Does handle just turn or is there a pivot to it also(tip of handle moves towards wall)? Will make length harder to measure right.

Comment: Could you have mounted it deeper so just the handle was on the surface?

Comment: @crip659 Handle rotates and moves from the wall to the floor.

Comment: @SolarMike, I haven't checked yet if I can insert it deeper. I will have a look. My first guest is that it is not possible.

Comment: Just checked on google.  There are chrome paints, but do not know if they are good.  Imagine covering everything else near there would a good idea, if used.  With the pivot point, a tube might interfere with movement, if you had it fitting so inside tube does not show.

Comment: @crip659 I checked (I was in vacation) and the handle cannot interfere with movement. So a tube is totally possible. Also, it is not possible to mount the shaft deeper in the wall. Can only stay outside like that.